# View JMeter "Response Times Percintiles" in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jmeter, jenkins-plugins, jmeter-plugins

We are using JMeter's standard plugins set and we have "Response Times Percintiles" and "Response Times Distribution" as in the picture below:

[image: JMeter conf]

However, when we run those test on our Jenkins, we see only the standard report as in the picture below:

[image: Jenkins view]

Is there a way to make Jenkins show those diagrams also? We have already installed the jar for the standard plugins there.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This link will help you:

- https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2014/01/automating-jmeter-tests-maven-jenkins/

It explains the whole procedure

Comment: Actually, I was using this article to set up the profiles for the performance tests. However, I did not read the last section and there is the answer I was looking for : "With the help of a small Maven plugin, the jmeter-graph-maven-plugin, it is possible to easily integrate this graph-generation in a Maven build." That plugin can be incorporated quite as described on its site. The list of possible graphs that can be generated can be found here: http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JMeterPluginsCMD/